# How to convert WMF/EMF to PNG/JPEG in Python?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, vector-graphics, wmf

I need to convert a `.wmf` file to a `.png` format.

I can't use libraries under the *GPL license.

Solutions that use external dependencies (such as inkscape or libreoffice in a subprocess) are also not suitable for my project.
Using external libraries in the system(installed by `apt` or another package manager, not by `pip`) is also undesirable.

I tried using `Pillow`, but it gives out an `OSError` (because the project runs on Linux, and `Pillow` supports `.wmf` only on Windows):

```
from PIL import Image

def main():
    img = Image.open('test.wmf')
    img.save('test.png')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`OSError: cannot find loader for this WMF file`.

Comment: It's not impossible to parse wmf yourself, but it's not easy either. Good luck.

Comment: Can `https://pypi.org/project/pyopencv/` do it?

Comment: Raises this error:
`cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:971: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'`

Comment: @pete "pyopencv" "Released: Sep 25, 2010". you got the wrong package. and no, OpenCV isn't meant to handle any niche image format, and it does not handle this WMF thing. look for a library that is _just_ for image file reading/writing. imagemagick comes to mind. also, if WMF is a vector format, then all the usual "image processing" is inapplicable. you first have to ***rasterize*** the vector data into raster data. I don't think you realize the computational complexity of this task, or the decisions you as the user have to make for that to go well.

Comment: Here's the spec if you want to do it yourself: https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/digformatspecs/WindowsMetafileFormat(wmf)Specification.pdf.  Probably find something that rasterizes it to .jpg or another raster format that can then be converted to .jpg.